About interchanging the order of two particular series
I asked to proof the following:
If $|z|<1$, then
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nz^n}{1-z^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{z^n}{(1-z^n)^2}.$$
My try: Since $|z|<1$,  the series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}z^n$ converges to $\frac{z^n}{1-z^n}$. Thus, we get that
$$\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{nz^n}{1-z^n} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}(z^n)^m = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}n(z^n)^m.$$
If $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\sum_{m=1}^{\infty}n(z^n)^m = \sum_{m=1}^{\infty}\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(z^m)^n$, we are done because $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}n(z^m)^n = \frac{z^m}{(1-z^m)^2}.$ I must prove that the double serie is absolutely convergent to conclude what I want. Here is where I'm stuck.
Can anyone help me to advance, please?

$\sum_{n\ge 1}z^n=\frac z{1-z}$

For large $n$, $1-|z|^n > 1/2$, hence $\frac{|z|^n}{1-|z|^n} \leq 2|z|^n$.

Let $a^2$ be the modulus of the fixed complex number $z$ as in the OP, so $a^2=|z|\in[0,1)$, and $a\in[0,1)$. We are dealing with positive integers $m,n$ in the double series.
Observe that $mn\ge (m+n)/2$ because of
$\left(m-\frac 12\right)\left(n-\frac 12\right) \ge \left(1-\frac 12\right)\left(1-\frac 12\right)=\frac 14$.
We want now to show that the double series with terms $\ge 0$
$$
\sum_{m, n\ge 1} n\;|z|^{mn}
$$
is bounded. Replacing the coefficient $n$ by $mn$ makes the above quantity bigger. We also replace the power $mn$ by the smaller power $(m+n)/2$ and get a bigger sum. So it is enough to show that the following quantity is bounded:
$$
\sum_{m, n\ge 1} mn\;|z|^{(m+n)/2}
=
\sum_{m, n\ge 1} mn\;a^{m+n}
=
\left(\sum_{m\ge 1} m\;a^m\right)
\left(\sum_{n\ge 1} n\;a^n\right)
=
\frac a{(1-a)^2}\cdot
\frac a{(1-a)^2}
<\infty\ .
$$
$\square$
